# Using inheritance setUp() and tearDown() methods in nose tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, nosetests

I have a general test class in my nosetests suit and some sub-classes, inheriting from it.

The config is likewise:

```
class CGeneral_Test(object)::
    """This class defines the general testcase"""
    def __init__ (self):
        do_some_init()
        print "initialisation of general class done!"

    def setUp(self):
        print "this is the general setup method"
        do_setup()

    def tearDown(self):
        print "this is the general teardown method"
        do_teardown()
```

Now, I have the subclasses which looks like this:

```
class CIPv6_Test(CGeneral_Test):
    """This class defines the sub, inherited testcase"""
    def __init__ (self):
        super(CIPv6_Test, self).__init__()
        do_some_sub_init()
        print "initialisation of sub class done!"

    def setUp(self):
        print "this is the per-test sub setup method"
        do_sub_setup()

    def test_routing_64(self):
        do_actual_testing_scenarios()

    def tearDown(self):
        print "this is the  per-test sub teardown method"
        do_sub_teardown()
```

So, what I want to achieve would be that each test would invoke both the sub-class and the super class setUp methods.
Hence, the desired order of test is:

```
Base Setup
Inherited Setup
This is a some test.
Inherited Teardown
Base Teardown
```

Of course, this can be achieved by calling    `CGeneral_Test.setUp(self)` from the inherited    `setUp()` method.

Is there any configuration in which this behaviour is achieved by default without specifically invoke the super setUp and tearDown methods?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you need not specify `CGeneral_Test`. You didn't in `CIPv6_Test.__init__`, and you can use the same strategy here:

```
class CIPv6_Test(CGeneral_Test):
    def setUp(self):
        super(CIPv6_Test, self).setUp()
        print "this is the per-test sub setup method"
        do_sub_setup()
```